# Apache whitelist a single location, but require basic auth for everything else

Tags: security, apache-2.2, http-authentication

I'm sure this is simple, but Google is not my friend this morning.

The goal is:

/public... is openly accessible

everything else (including /) requires basic auth.

This is a WSGI app, with a single WSGI script (it's a django site, if that matters..)

I have this:

```
<Location /public>
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
</Location>
<Directory />
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "My Test Server"
  AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
  Require valid-user
</Directory>
```

With this configuration, basic auth works fine, but the `Location` directive is totally ignored. I'm not surprised, as according to [this](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/sections.html) (see How the Sections are Merged), the `Directory` directive is processed first.

I'm sure I'm missing something, but since Directory applies to a filesystem location, and I really only have the one `Directory` at `/`, and it's a `Location` that I wish to allow access to, but `Directory` always overrides `Location`...

**EDIT**

I'm using Apache 2.2, which doesn't support `AuthType None`.

Answer (score 2):

For Apache 2.0, set `AuthType None` within your `<Location /public>` stanza:

```
<Location /public>
  AuthType None
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
</Location>
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_authn_core.html#AuthType

Comment: Sadly, I'm using Apache 2.2, which doesn't support AuthType None.

Answer (score 2):

For Apache 2.2 (and probably others in the 2 series older than 2.3):

```
<Location /public>
  Satisfy any
  Allow from all
</Location>
<Location />
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "My Test Server"
  AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
  Require valid-user
</Location>
```

Comment: This doesn't work - I still get the auth box on the location I am trying to remove it from. I hate Apache so much...